# watir webdriver using a variable

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir

I am having trouble using a variable in browser reference. I am trying to pass the field type such as ul, ol etc. The code works if I type ol, but I would like to use the pass variable labeled 'field'. I recieve an "undefined method for field" error.

I have tried also using #{field}, but that does not work either.  The error is that field is not defined.

```
def CheckNewPageNoUl(browser, field, text1, output)

  browser.a(:id => 'submitbtn').hover
  browser.a(:id => 'submitbtn').click
  output.puts("text1  #{text1}")      
  browser.body(:id => 'page').wait_until_present
  if browser.table.field.exists?
    output.puts(" #{text1} was found in CheckNewPageNoUl")
  end
end

field = "ol" 

text1 = "<ol>"

CheckText.CheckNewPageNoUl(b, field, text1, outputt)
```

Comment: In the code example, the `field` variable is a String.  The browser object is expecting a method where the class is `Watir::OList` (or `Watir::Ol` in watir-classic).

Comment: I understand that field is a string but why doesn't it get translated to 'ol' in the line of code so that it gets interpreted as "browser.table.ol.exists?"  I was hoping to use the method for ul, ol, li, etc by passing a variable and not making several more methods.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To translate a string into a method call, use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send), which can take two parameters:

1. The method name (as string or symbol)
2. Arguments for the method (optional)

Some examples:

```
field = 'ol'
browser.send(field).exists?
#=> Translates to browser.ol.exists?

specifiers = {:text => 'text', :class => 'class'}
browser.send(field, specifiers).exists?
#=> Translates to browser.ol(:text => 'text', :class => 'class').exists?
```

For your code, you would want to have:

```
if browser.table.send(field).exists?
  output.puts(" #{text1} was found in CheckNewPageNoUl")
end
```